# Django SItemap Index NoReverseMatch at /sitemap.xml

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to implement Sitemap Index but I'm getting the below error on sitemap.xml. sitemap-posts.xml and sitemap-categories.xml works fine.

**Error**

```
NoReverseMatch at /sitemap.xml

Reverse for 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'section': 'categories'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

**sitemap.py**

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap

from .models import Post, Category

class PostSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = 'daily'
    priority = 0.5

    def items(self):
        return Post.objects.published()

    def lastmod(self, obj):
        return obj.mod_date

class CategorySitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = 'daily'
    priority = 0.5

    def items(self):
        return Category.objects.all()

    def lastmod(self, obj):
        return obj.created_date
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.sitemaps import views as sitemap

from . import views
from .sitemaps import PostSitemap, CategorySitemap

sitemaps = {
    'posts': PostSitemap,
    'categories': CategorySitemap,
}

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', sitemap.index, { 'sitemaps': sitemaps }, 
        name='app1-sitemap'),
    url(r'^sitemap-(?P<section>.+)\.xml$', sitemap.sitemap, { 'sitemaps': sitemaps }, 
        name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap1'),
]
```

Please help me to fix this error.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace and also your `views.py`.

Comment: You're calling the first url with the kwargs for the second url.

Answer (score 2):

Change name from 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap1' to 'sitemaps'. Apparently it uses that name for resolution.

```
name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap1'
```

My urls look exactly like this and it works right, when I changed the name, I got an error close to yours.

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap, index
    urlpatterns += [
            url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', cache_page(86400)(index), {'sitemaps': sitemaps, 'sitemap_url_name': 'sitemaps'}),
            url(r'^sitemap-(?P<section>.+)\.xml$', cache_page(86400)(sitemap), {'sitemaps': sitemaps}, name='sitemaps' )
        ]
```

sitemap_url_name required because I'm caching.

Comment: I have changed it to 'sitemaps' but still getting the same error. Also tried with 'sitemap' but no luck.

Comment: I updated the code with an exact working copy I have, got an error similar to yours when I changed the name. You may ignore the caching bit.

Comment: Adding the `sitemap_url_name` to the url dict is what fixed it for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the name of second URL conf. should be

```
name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'
```

which refers to the official doc
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#creating-a-sitemap-index

instead of what you use

```
name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap1'
```

and it works on my computer.